# Create database in MongoHQ from C#

Tags: c#, mongohq

I'm trying to create a Database in MongoHQ from C# code. I read that by just calling

`server.GetDatabase("DBName");`

it creates the DB if it doesn't exist, nevertheless nothing is created.

Is it possible to do what I want to do? I have a free account =/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a collection for the database to get created.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm creating the collection as well, but I'm not inserting everything, yet, so I'm going to try that real quick.

Comment: I get an invalid credential error when I try to save the collection, but I don't get any errors when making the connection. Could it be because there is no users in the new DB?

Comment: Your connectionstring should have your username/password.
You could try the sample app found at http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#getting-started-with-csharp-driver
and use your MonogHQ connectionstring.
Or edit your orignial question and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

this is Jason from MongoHQ.

If you have a free account, you probably already have a database and would not have access to create new databases without either:

a) creating the new database through the MongoHQ web application.

b) using our MongoHQ API to automatically create new databases.

Also, since you don't have admin-level access on the free plans, you will need to specify the database you are accessing and you can then list the collections for that database.

Hope this helps!